# Insert query in stored procedure not working in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, insert

This is probably simple but I can't figure it out. I have a package which has a stored procedure responsible for doing inserts, deletes or updates to the main table based on information in the staging table. The schema for both the main and staging table is the same with the exception that the staging table has a column called 'ACTION' which determines the operation to be performed.

Queries for updates and deletes work but the query for insert in the stored procedure never inserts data in the main table. Here's the insert query in the stored procedure I am using. Please HELP #goingNuts

I also tried explicitly specifying a commit, that didn't work. I tried using alias `GSC`, still no luck.

```
--Inserts
INSERT
INTO GS_CASE
  (
    SYSTEM,
    CASE_ID,
    DISPLAY_ID,
    OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
    OWNER_MIDDLENAME,
    OWNER_LASTNAME
  )
SELECT GSC.SYSTEM,
  GSC.CASE_ID,
  GSC.DISPLAY_ID,
  GSC.OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
  GSC.OWNER_MIDDLENAME,
  GSC.OWNER_LASTNAME
FROM GS_STAGING_CASE GSC WHERE GSC.ACTION = 'INSERT';
```

Table schemas below:

```
  CREATE TABLE "COSI"."GS_CASE" 
   (    "SYSTEM" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CASE_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "DISPLAY_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "OWNER_FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "OWNER_MIDDLENAME" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "OWNER_LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "COSI_DATA" ;


CREATE TABLE GS_STAGING_CASE 
(
  SYSTEM VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, CASE_ID VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, DISPLAY_ID VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, OWNER_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) 
, OWNER_MIDDLENAME VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) 
, OWNER_LASTNAME VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)  
, ACTION VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE COSI_DATA 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS;
```

I have indexes on the GS_Case table but not on staging

Comment: Are you missing the "values" part?
`Insert into table (col1, col2)
values ( Select col1_val, col2_val
`From table
where condition);

Comment: @BrianRobbins it doesn't work with values you have to use either `values` or `select`

Comment: show us the source code of your procedure, what error do you have?

Comment: Are you getting an error or it just not insert the expected rows?

Comment: Does GSC.ACTION = 'INSERT' retreve any data from GS_STAGING_CASE table. Could you run a SELECT DISTINCT ACTION FROM GS_STAGING_CASE  and provide us the results.

Comment: Not related to your question, but your tags appear to contradict each other.  I don't think oracle uses tsql.

Comment: There are no errors. It just doesn't insert. It says the run is successful anytime i try

Comment: @gouri-shankar-aechoor Yes, gsc.action = 'insert' returns data. 7 rows to be exact. When i take the same insert statement and run it in the editor in sql developer, it works. Just doesn't work in my stored procedure

Comment: Remember Oracle could be case sensitive - So check the case - is it "insert" OR "INSERT" in the table?

Comment: I ran the query "SELECT DISTINCT ACTION FROM GS_STAGING_CASE ;" and it returned only one value => INSERT

Comment: @TMNT2014 i checke dthat too. It's all caps.

Comment: Whats the code in the stored procedure like after the Insert statement?

Comment: @TMNT2014 right now, i have explicitly specified 'COMMIT;'. And then after that is an update statement

Comment: the update statement works. Let me do something and comment out all queries after and see if it works

Comment: @TMNT2014 Ok...this is really really weird. Commenting out the update and delete queries in the package got my insert statement to work but why??

Comment: Does your table GS_CASE have any triggers associated with it?

Comment: @TMNT2014 No triggers

Comment: Can you share the table definitions of the two tables?

Comment: @TMNT2014 Sorry for the late response. Updated the question with the table definitions

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of you insert is good.

Did your select return value ?

if you have no compilation error : ORA-00900 to ORA-01499...

Thank you to encapsulate your insert in a block with an exception to see if there is an error during the insert.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT
    INTO GS_CASE
      (
        SYSTEM,
        CASE_ID,
        DISPLAY_ID,
        OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
        OWNER_MIDDLENAME,
        OWNER_LASTNAME
      )
    SELECT GSC.SYSTEM,
      GSC.CASE_ID,
      GSC.DISPLAY_ID,
      GSC.OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
      GSC.OWNER_MIDDLENAME,
      GSC.OWNER_LASTNAME
    FROM GS_STAGING_CASE GSC WHERE GSC.ACTION = 'INSERT';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error code : ' || SQLCODE || ' Message : ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END;
```

Comment: I currently write my exceptions to a log file and nothing is in the log file either :( Let me comment out all other queries and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Ok...this is really really weird. Commenting out the update and delete queries in the package got my insert statement to work but why??

Comment: your insert should work if your select returns values. Now you can try another approach. Which would also more efficient. Bulk collect your result in a collection and after make a forall with the insert

Comment: maybe because in your algo you will never fit in your condition for the insert

Answer (score 0):

Ok i couldn't figure what was going on out but I re-ordered my stored procedure: having the updates and deletes first and moving the inserts to be the last operation. Doing that worked, and everything is working as should be.

However, if anyone comes up with an idea or logic behind why this is (maybe something with Oracle's locking model), would love to know

Answer (score -1):

There can be 2 reasons ...

1. When this insert is execute then GS_STAGING_CASE table didn't had any data so nothing is inserted.
2. It is inserting the data into GS_CASE table but again deleted by further statements in the procedure.

To be sure what is happening, try printing the counts using dbms_output.put_line and **SQL%ROWCOUNT** to see how many records are inserted by your insert statement

see below a sample...block on how to print...

```
 -- don't forget below set else dbms_output will not print...
 set serveroutput on size 1000000

 declare
 v_count number(10);
 v_insert_count number(10);
 begin

   /* this will print the number of rows in this table */
   select count(1) Into v_count from GS_STAGING_CASE;
   dbms_output.put_line('Rows in GS_STAGING_CASE = '||v_count);

   /* Your insert statement is here. */

   /* this should be just after your insert statement */
   v_insert_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   dbms_output.put_line('Rows Inserted into GS_CASE = '||v_insert_count);

   commit;

 end;
 /
```

Comment: thanks for responding, here's the outcome Connecting to the database
    Rows in GS_STAGING_CASE = 4
    Rows Inserted into GS_CASE = 0
    Process exited.
    Disconnecting from the database

Comment: That means these 4 rows in that table doesnot meet your where clause where GSC.ACTION = 'INSERT'

Comment: It does because i edited the first statement you sent to say this

Comment: select count(1) Into v_count from GS_STAGING_CASE where ACTION = 'INSERT';